# Is there a way to track a pre detected object in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have an object I'd like to track using OpenCV. In my detection algorithm I can create bounded boxes around the objects it sees, and can create a target object to track properly. My detection algorithm works well, but I want to pass this object to a tracking algorithm.I can't quite get this done without having to re write the detection and image display issues. I'm working with an NVIDA Jetson Nanoboard with an Intel Realsense camera if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV DNN module comes with python samples of state of the art trackers. I've heard good things about the "siamese" based ones. [Have a look](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/dnn)

Also the OpenCV contrib repo contains a whole module of various trackers. Give those a try first. They have a simple API.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried using the contrib repo for the KCF tracker. It works fine on my laptop at home, but then when I try to use it on a jupyter notebook on a lab machine it has issues connecting to a video capture. I think at this point I'm just going in circles and ending up back at the same conclusion.

Comment: if you have issues with video capture, that would be due to the videoio module and a separate but solvable problem. set a specific apiPreference in your VideoCapture() initialization (e.g. CAP_FFMPEG), use getBuildInformation() to check if OpenCV was built with ffmpeg and/or gstreamer. if it was but it still doesn't work, the system can't find the library at runtime.

Comment: Great. Thanks so much Christoph, I'll look into the build information